How can I get Laravel's Http client to return a rejected promise for a failed request?
Laravel's Http client has a throw() method which makes calls fail with an exception for synchronous calls:
$resp = Http::throw()->get('https://www.google.com/fake'); // throws RequestException

However, in async mode, it responds with an exception rather than a rejected promise:
$resp = Http::async()->throw()->get('https://www.google.com/fake')->wait();
// $resp is an instance of RequestException

This behavior seems very undesirable; is there any way to get async throw to result in a rejected promise?
I'm using laravel 11.
